# Mvc : displaying a List<student> from the database in a text file with click of button

Tags: c#

I am new to mvc. I have a controller with two methods. I want to return a list to a text
file on the click of a button. I have been trying to figure out a way how I can pass
the list to the CreateReportFile method but no luck. It works very well for stringbuilder objects.

Do you have an idea of how I can display the List in a text file?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download File", "CreateReportFile");


         public FileStreamResult CreateReportFile()
                {
                    //todo: add some data from your database into that string:
                    var string_with_your_data = string.Empty;              
                    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string_with_your_data);
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                    return File(stream, "text/plain", "Report" + DateTime.Now + ".txt");
                }



                public List<Student> GetStudents()
                {
                    return new List<Student>()
                    {
                        new Student() {firstname="james",lastname="john",emailAddress="james.john@yahoo.com"},
                        new Student() {firstname="patric",lastname="swayze",emailAddress="patric.swayze@yahoo.com"},
                        new Student() {firstname="james",lastname="john",emailAddress="james.john@yahoo.com"},
                        new Student() {firstname="toy",lastname="gas",emailAddress="toy.gas@yahoo.com"}
                    };
                }
```

Comment: So is your problem that you cant save things to text file or cant get the list of students to createReport?

Comment: I am not able to send that list to a text file and save it as a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to get the students list into that string you are writing to the file you could try:

```
public FileStreamResult CreateReportFile()
{
    List<Student> students = GetStudents();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Student s in students)
        sb.AppendLine(s.firstname + ", " + s.lastname + ", " + s.emailAddress);

    var string_with_your_data = sb.ToString();
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string_with_your_data);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    return File(stream, "text/plain", "Report" + DateTime.Now + ".txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you should have to do is add this to make it a string and then send the data.

```
 foreach(Student test in GetStudents())
            {
                string_with_your_data += test.firstname + ", " + test.lastname + ", " + test.emailAddress + "\r\n";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to convert List object into text you will need to create a method that does that OR you can use a Serializer, but that will format it into json or xml.

To convert the object yourself in your student object you can override ToString with something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{ 
    return String.Format("firstname={0}, lastname={1}, emailAddress={2}", firstname, lastname, emailAddress);
}
```

Then you can loop through your list

```
string mystring = string.Empty;
foreach(var student in Students)
     mystring += student.ToString() + "\n";
```

Just some ideas that might get you started.

Comment: `string.Join("\n", Students)` is much more concise, and will perform better than appending strings in a `for` loop.